# Regular Expression to obtain inner text

Tags: java, regex

I want to obtain the highlighted part from the following text:

Linux version **3.10.49-g5796782** (d00903065@ubuntu)

I've been trying with Pattern and Matcher from the Java library but haven't been able to succeed. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's my code, I've tried some of the answers but for some reaon it won't have any matches:

`String s = "Linux version 3.10.49-g5796782 (d00903065@ubuntu)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'^\\D+([-.\\w]+)'");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        s = matcher.group(1);
    } else {
        s = "no match";
    }`

Comment: Could you provide more strings ? Or is it the only string ?

Comment: My bad, the string will always have Linux version at the beginning  so I would want to obtain the alphanumeric code after version and before a white-space.

Comment: How have you got such string? Maybe it's worth to change command line for printing linux version. For example `uname -r` returns what you're interested.

Comment: I'm reading the /proc/version file using adb to get an Android device's kernel version.

Comment: concerning your code in "Edit" block: remove `'` symbols from pattern and it should work

Comment: Thanks! That fixes it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
(?<=version\s)(\S+)
```

Here's a [working example](https://regex101.com/r/bW6pI1/1).

Comment: I get no matches.
`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(?<=version\\s)(\\S+)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);`

Comment: What if you run it with the `find(..)` function? @Tuco [see here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a reg exp, if it is guaranteed to appear after `Linux version`, you could just do:

```
str.split(" ")[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
^\D+([-.\w]+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/pK6iL5/1).
Remember to double escape the backslashes in `Java`, so it becomes:

```
^\\D+([-.\\w]+)
```

And use the first group.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned the string always starts with `Linux version`, I made the regex more specific and Java code will be :

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String pattern = "Linux version\\s*(\\d+.\\d+.\\d+-\\w+)\\s+.*";
    String input = "Linux version 3.10.49-g5796782 (d00903065@ubuntu)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.find())
    {
       System.out.println("Linux version is : " + m.group(1));  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Darn, a lot of people beat me to the punch on this, but since I made the regex already:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    String s = "Linux version 3.10.49-g5796782 (d00903065@ubuntu)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s+([a-z-A-Z0-9.-]+)\\s+(?:[()a-zA-Z0-9@)]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        s = matcher.group(1);
    } else {
        s = "no match";
    }
    System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I matched the entire string, which seems a little bit excessive now that I went back and read what you needed.   This will handle if there's ever a number in one of the first 2 words though, which seems less plausible.